# Change index of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to change the index of an array but I don't know how to do it..
The following array

```
array(
0 => array ( 'id' => 33, 'name' => 'test' )
1 => array ( 'id' => 37, 'name' => 'test2' )
)
```

should become - if i want the index

```
array(
33 => array ( 'id' => 33, 'name' => 'test' )
37 => array ( 'id' => 37, 'name' => 'test2' )
)
```

or if i want the name

```
array(
test => array ( 'id' => 33, 'name' => 'test' )
test2 => array ( 'id' => 37, 'name' => 'test2' )
)
```

also for a multi-dimensional array

```
array(
0 => array ( 'id' => 33, 'details' => array (name => 'test' , age ='50' ) )
1 => array ( 'id' => 37, 'details' => array (name => 'test2' , age ='60' ) )
)
```

to index replace 0 and 1 with the name - test or test2

right now I made a function but is not working with multi dimensional arrays

```
function index_array( $array, $index ){

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $new_array[$index] = $array[$key];  
}

return $new_array;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Because it is as simple as setting up a array like the sub arrays in your example.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array(33 => $oldarray[0], 37 => $oldarray[1]);
$array = array('test' => $oldarray[0], 'test2' => $oldarray[1]);
```

Since the right-hand-side of the expression is evaluated before the assignment you could also use `$array` on both sides  instead of a different variable name.

Comment: your answer is good but is not working with multi-dimensional arrays.. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a mapping table for the first part, or a simple `foreach` for the second part:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    0 => array( 'id' => 33, 'name' => 'test' ),
    1 => array( 'id' => 37, 'name' => 'test2' )
);

/* Convert to other indexes */
$mapping = array(
    0 => 33,
    1 => 37
);

foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    unset($arr[$k]);
    $arr[$mapping[$k]] = $v;
}

print_r($arr);

/* Convert key to name field */
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    unset($arr[$k]);
    $arr[$v['name']] = $v;
}

print_r($arr);
```

**EDIT**: Now that I read your question again, the first part is actually the same as the second, but then just with the `id` field instead of the `name` field.

**EDIT2**: Note that you'd have to use another array to write to, to avoid overrides, which will occur when the `id` field is used as a replacement.

Comment: The multi-dimensional part is VERY easy once you have the above code, left as an excercise for you to do.